# How to capitalise the capital of Mongolia

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations

If you're referring to the abbreviated form of the Ulan Bator (also spelt Ulaanbaatar), the capital of Mongolia, in a reasonably informal context, is it typically "UB", "Ub", or are both ok?

Comment: I suspect there's no answer to your question. You're asking how native speakers would normally refer to the capital of Mongolia in an informal setting, but this situation just doesn't arise often enough for there to be a rule for it. If the capital is Ulaanbaatar then speakers will refer to it as Ulaanbaatar. It would help if you give details for the context, there's a big difference in writing style between writing a letter to a friend and writing in shorthand over instant messenger programs.

Comment: That's hard.  If the typical spelling is 2 distinct words, I would use UB, but if it is usually one word, then I might use Ul or possibly still UB because of where the sylables lie in the word.  I don't think I would use Ub, unless I know that this was the correct abbreviation.  This one probably requures very specialized knowledge to answer 100% correctly.

Comment: I don't think it's Ub - If I see Ub, I might think you're referring to an element's name.

Comment: In the US, we use initials sometimes for those city names with multiple words, like LA or D.C., and sometimes not, like New Orleans and Baton Rouge. If you abbreviate Ulan Bator, very few people will know what you mean unless you define it first. If you're the one defining it, you can choose whatever makes sense to you. Only states in the US have "official" abbreviations for the postal system.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is UB. Abbreviations are mostly full capital. Also Bator has a capital B. It is true that as ColleenV said, you need to define it first. For example, it would be completely unclear to say:

> I am going to UB now

But if you had sentences before, it would be understandable:

> Ulan Bator is the capital of Mongolia. I am actually going to UB this week